# Slide toggle Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow

I've been looking for ways to make an enqueue of the right library of jquery ui but i dont see there is one for that, any ideas of how to use this without getting error?

```
        jQuery('#menu_desktop').toggle("slide", {direction: "left"});
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

My jquery ui enqueue

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', '1', true);

wp_enqueue_script('menu_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui'), '1', true);
```

My error

```
jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1:2 Uncaught TypeError: k.easing[this.easing] is not a function
    at init.run (jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1:2)
    at u (jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1:2)
    at Function.k.fx.tick (jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1:2)
    at lt (jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1:2)
```

Libraries are being imported

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you're attempting to enqueue the script - the link you provided has the correct info (jQuery UI Core is the one you want)... ...so not sure what the error you're getting is.

Comment: @TonyDjukic hi tony i just updated the post

Comment: The error is basically telling you that the easing function isn't available.  Instead of .toggle() can you try .slideToggle().  Do you have a URL you can share?

Comment: @TonyDjukic it works but without the direction argument which i dont need :c

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery UI is included in the Wordpress Core, you don't need to load it from the CDN. Please try to change your wp_enqueue_scripts from

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', '1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('menu_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui'), '1', true);
```

to

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-slide');
wp_enqueue_script('menu_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core','jquery-effects-slide'), '1', true);
```

Also be sure to call for the Slide Effect within a document.ready function ;)

Comment: It does not work :c still getting the same error

Comment: Can you try changing your jquery-code to this: jQuery('#menu_desktop').toggle("slide", {direction: "left", easing:'linear'});
?